# Using a column, with lists of values, to specify from which columns to create another list of values

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have data as follows:

## Previous solution

```
library(dplyr)
dat_in <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"
), `[0,25)` = c(5L, 0L), `[25,50)` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,100)` = c(38L, 
3L), `[50,100)` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,250)` = c(43L, 5L), `[100,500)` = c(0L, 
0L), `[250,500)` = c(27L, 12L), `[500,1000)` = c(44L, 0L), `[1000,1500)` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1500,3000)` = c(0L, 0L), `[500,1000000]` = c(0L, 53L), 
    `[1000,1000000]` = c(20L, 0L), `[3000,1000000]` = c(0L, 0L
    ), Sum_bin = c(177, 73), strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1e+06))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

I previously used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968964/put-the-values-in-a-row-which-are-larger-than-zero-in-a-list-of-lists) to get the columns with frequencies above zero.

```
out <- dat_in %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(rn = rn, 
            freq =list(c_across(-c(rn,strata)))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(freq = list(freq[which(freq > 0)]))
```

[image]

## New issue

Regrettably this solution was not robust enough for the data (because for example the `[0,25)` strata actually had zero frequencies for `type_B`).

What I would like to try is to create a list of values in the `freq` column, based on the `strata` column.

```
[[1]]
[1]       0      25     100     250     500    1000 1000000

[[2]]
[1]       0      25     100     250     500 1000000
```

So for the first row, the values in `[0,25), [25,100), [100,250), [250,500), [500,1000) and [1000,1000000)` should be collected.

**But the following row has different strata values**

For the second row the values `[0,25), [25,100), [100,250), [250,500), and [500,1000000)` should be collected.

I am having a hard time thinking of an approach to do this. Can anyone suggest a good approach?

## Desired output:

```
dat_out <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"), freq = list(c(5, 38, 
43, 27, 44, 20, 177), c(0, 3, 5, 12, 53, 73))), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

[image]

Comment: Will the strata always be equal to the columns? Or the strata can be different from the column?

Comment: @onyambu I am not completely sure I understand,, but if I do, they should always be equal. It is a frequency table, and the `strata`  are the values I fed to `cut2`.

Comment: I think we should now if strata is always for these columns 0,25,100, 250, 500, 1000000. Or is strata depending on values before?

Comment: @TarJae In that case, no they are not. They are already not the same for the example I gave. Notice that the two rows have different strata.

Comment: @TarJae, I noticed I had a small typo, which may have caused the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat_in %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(rn, strata)) %>%
  extract(name, c('lower', 'upper'), '(\\d+),(\\d+)', convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  filter(lower%in%strata[[1]] & upper %in% strata[[1]]) %>%
  group_by(upper,.add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(value), .groups = 'drop_last') %>%
  group_modify(~add_row(.,freq = sum(.$freq))) %>%
  summarise(freq = list(freq))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  rn     freq     
  <chr>  <list>   
1 Type_A <dbl [7]>
2 Type_B <dbl [6]>
```

with the freq column:

```
[[1]]
[1]   5  38  43  27  44  20 177

[[2]]
[1]  0  3  5 12 53 73
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! It turned out to be quite a bit more complicated than I first thought.

Comment: @Tom that is because of the strata groupings.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_in %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::select(where(~ any(unlist(.) !=0))) %>% 
  select(-Sum_bin, -strata) %>% 
  nest(freq = -rn)
```

which gives:

```
  rn     freq            
  <chr>  <list>          
1 Type_A <tibble [1 x 7]>
2 Type_B <tibble [1 x 7]>
```

Or this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_in %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::select(where(~ any(unlist(.) !=0))) %>% 
  select(-Sum_bin, -strata) %>% 
  unite(new_var, -rn, sep = ", ", remove = TRUE) %>% 
  nest(freq = -rn)
```

which gives this:

```
  rn     freq            
  <chr>  <list>          
1 Type_A <tibble [1 x 1]>
2 Type_B <tibble [1 x 1]>
```

Comment: I also thought the same, then I realized the strata are different and you have to take them into account. Your result is different from the desired output. Note that for Type_B the length is 6 and not 7

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not completely work. For row one, there should be 7 values (which is the case), but for row 2, there should only be six. The point was that it only picks up the categories which are listed in the `strata` column.