# Make a list out of frequencies, concatenating categories to that list

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71986426/using-a-column-with-lists-of-values-to-specify-from-which-columns-to-create-an), by onyambu:

## New data

```
    dat_in_new <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"
), `[0,25) east` = c(1269L, 85L), `[0,25) north` = c(364L, 21L
), `[0,25) south` = c(1172L, 97L), `[0,25) west` = c(549L, 49L
), `[25,50) east` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,50) north` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,50) south` = c(0L, 
0L), `[25,50) west` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,100) east` = c(579L, 220L
), `[25,100) north` = c(406L, 58L), `[25,100) south` = c(1048L, 
316L), `[25,100) west` = c(764L, 131L), `[50,100) east` = c(0L, 
0L), `[50,100) north` = c(0L, 0L), `[50,100) south` = c(0L, 0L
), `[50,100) west` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,250) east` = c(441L, 149L
), `[100,250) north` = c(224L, 45L), `[100,250) south` = c(521L, 
247L), `[100,250) west` = c(770L, 124L), `[100,500) east` = c(0L, 
0L), `[100,500) north` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,500) south` = c(0L, 
0L), `[100,500) west` = c(0L, 0L), `[250,500) east` = c(232L, 
172L), `[250,500) north` = c(207L, 40L), `[250,500) south` = c(202L, 
148L), `[250,500) west` = c(457L, 153L), `[500,1000) east` = c(103L, 
0L), `[500,1000) north` = c(185L, 0L), `[500,1000) south` = c(66L, 
0L), `[500,1000) west` = c(200L, 0L), `[1000,1500) east` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1000,1500) north` = c(0L, 0L), `[1000,1500) south` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1000,1500) west` = c(0L, 0L), `[1500,3000) east` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1500,3000) north` = c(0L, 0L), `[1500,3000) south` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1500,3000) west` = c(0L, 0L), `[500,1000000] east` = c(0L, 
288L), `[500,1000000] north` = c(0L, 120L), `[500,1000000] south` = c(0L, 
229L), `[500,1000000] west` = c(0L, 175L), `[1000,1000000] east` = c(53L, 
0L), `[1000,1000000] north` = c(82L, 0L), `[1000,1000000] south` = c(23L, 
0L), `[1000,1000000] west` = c(63L, 0L), `[3000,1000000] east` = c(0L, 
0L), `[3000,1000000] north` = c(0L, 0L), `[3000,1000000] south` = c(0L, 
0L), `[3000,1000000] west` = c(0L, 0L), Sum_table_in = c(9980, 
2867), strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 
25, 100, 250, 500, 1e+06))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

## Old data and solution

```
library(dplyr)
dat_in <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"
), `[0,25)` = c(5L, 0L), `[25,50)` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,100)` = c(38L, 
3L), `[50,100)` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,250)` = c(43L, 5L), `[100,500)` = c(0L, 
0L), `[250,500)` = c(27L, 12L), `[500,1000)` = c(44L, 0L), `[1000,1500)` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1500,3000)` = c(0L, 0L), `[500,1000000]` = c(0L, 53L), 
    `[1000,1000000]` = c(20L, 0L), `[3000,1000000]` = c(0L, 0L
    ), Sum_bin = c(177, 73), strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1e+06))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

dat_in %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(rn, strata)) %>%
  tidyr::extract(name, c('lower', 'upper'), '(\\d+),(\\d+)', convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  filter(lower%in%strata[[1]] & upper %in% strata[[1]]) %>%
  group_by(upper,.add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(value), .groups = 'drop_last') %>%
  group_modify(~add_row(.,freq = sum(.$freq))) %>%
  summarise(freq = list(freq))
```

[image]

## Question

For the new data, there are many more values, because there are values for `east`, `north`, `south` and `west`. These values should be concatenated to make one long list of frequencies, one for each type.

The start can be adapted as follows:

```
part1 <- dat_in_new %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(rn, strata)) %>%
  tidyr::extract(name, c('lower', 'upper', 'rest'), '(\\d+),(\\d+)[\\]\\)]\\s*(\\w*)', convert = TRUE)  %>% 
  select(-where(is_all_na))
```

But I get stuck in the following part, because I do not really understand the lines after `group_by(rn)`, especially the `.groups = 'drop_last'` part ([link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html)). I usually just run the code line by line to see what happens, but for this solution that did not really help:

```
part2 <- part2 %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  filter(lower%in%strata[[1]] & upper %in% strata[[1]]) %>%
  group_by(upper,.add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(value), .groups = 'drop_last') %>%
  group_modify(~add_row(.,freq = sum(.$freq))) %>%
  summarise(freq = list(freq))
```

Currently, the code runs, but I end up with the old outcome. How should I adapt this code to add all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `pivot_longer` as

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat_in_new %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(rn, strata, Sum_table_in),
  names_to = c("lower", "upper", "direction"),
   names_pattern = "\\[(\\d+),(\\d+)[\\)\\]]\\s+(\\S+$)",
    values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(rn, direction) %>%
  filter(lower%in%strata[[1]] & upper %in% strata[[1]]) %>%
  group_by(upper,.add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(value), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
  group_modify(~add_row(.,freq = sum(.$freq))) %>%
  summarise(freq = list(freq), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  rn     direction freq     
  <chr>  <chr>     <list>   
1 Type_A east      <int [7]>
2 Type_A north     <int [7]>
3 Type_A south     <int [7]>
4 Type_A west      <int [7]>
5 Type_B east      <int [6]>
6 Type_B north     <int [6]>
7 Type_B south     <int [6]>
8 Type_B west      <int [6]>
```

---

If we want only by 'rn'

```
dat_in_new %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(rn, strata, Sum_table_in),
  names_to = c("lower", "upper", "direction"),
   names_pattern = "\\[(\\d+),(\\d+)[\\)\\]]\\s+(\\S+$)",
    values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(rn, direction) %>%
  filter(lower%in%strata[[1]] & upper %in% strata[[1]]) %>%
  group_by(upper,.add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(value), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
  group_modify(~add_row(.,freq = sum(.$freq))) %>% group_by(rn) %>%
  summarise(freq = list(freq), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  rn     freq      
  <chr>  <list>    
1 Type_A <int [28]>
2 Type_B <int [24]>
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654856/putting-string-values-in-a-column-of-lists