# Putting string values in a column of lists

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyr

I have data that looks as follows (example data at the bottom):

```
# A tibble: 40 × 6
   rn    strata    lower upper   direction value        
   <chr> <list>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>        
 1 A     <dbl [6]> 0     25      East      0 (replaced) 
 2 A     <dbl [6]> 25    100     East      3 (replaced) 
 3 A     <dbl [6]> 100   500     East      3            
 4 A     <dbl [6]> 500   1000    East      4            
 5 A     <dbl [6]> 1000  1000000 East      5            
 6 A     <dbl [6]> 0     25      North     0 (replaced) 
 7 A     <dbl [6]> 25    100     North     0 (replaced) 
 8 A     <dbl [6]> 100   500     North     1            
 9 A     <dbl [6]> 500   1000    North     28 (replaced)
10 A     <dbl [6]> 1000  1000000 North     2            
# … with 30 more rows
```

I would like to concatenate all `value` entries by `rn, direction, upper`. This can almost be done with the following code:

```
dat_in_new <- dat %>%
    # One line for each rn-group
    group_by(rn, upper, direction) %>% 
    # Calculate the sum, not taking into account replaced values
    summarise(freq = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=TRUE), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
    group_modify(~add_row(.,freq = sum(.$value))) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(freq = list(freq), .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  rn    freq      
  <chr> <list>    
1 A     c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0)
2 B     c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 13, 0, 2, 1, 0, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

This solution now has the correct sum, because the `replaced` values should not be added to the sum. However they should be added to the `list`. I have been trying to separate the two, but I cannot figure it out.

## EDIT:

I thought it would maybe be possible to create another `value` column, say `value_string`, force `value` to numeric and keep `value_string` as strings, summarise both of them, get the sum from `value` and the values from `value_string`. But I can't figure out how to write the syntax.

## Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  rn    freq      
  <chr> <list>    
1 A     c("0 (replaced)", "0 (replaced)", ... )
2 B     c("0 (replaced)", "0 (replaced)", ... )
```

## Related questions:

[Make a list out of frequencies, concatenating categories to that list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142784/make-a-list-out-of-frequencies-concatenating-categories-to-that-list)

[Using a column, with lists of values, to specify from which columns to create another list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71986426/using-a-column-with-lists-of-values-to-specify-from-which-columns-to-create-an)

## DATA

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat <- structure(list(rn = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B"), strata = list(
    c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 
    1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 
    1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 
    25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06
    ), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 
    1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 
    1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 
    25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06
    ), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 
    1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 
    1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 
    25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06
    ), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 
    1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 
    1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 
    25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06
    ), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 
    1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 
    1000, 1e+06)), lower = c("0", "25", "100", "500", "1000", 
"0", "25", "100", "500", "1000", "0", "25", "100", "500", "1000", 
"0", "25", "100", "500", "1000", "0", "25", "100", "500", "1000", 
"0", "25", "100", "500", "1000", "0", "25", "100", "500", "1000", 
"0", "25", "100", "500", "1000"), upper = c("25", "100", "500", 
"1000", "1000000", "25", "100", "500", "1000", "1000000", "25", 
"100", "500", "1000", "1000000", "25", "100", "500", "1000", 
"1000000", "25", "100", "500", "1000", "1000000", "25", "100", 
"500", "1000", "1000000", "25", "100", "500", "1000", "1000000", 
"25", "100", "500", "1000", "1000000"), direction = c("East", 
"East", "East", "East", "East", "North", "North", "North", "North", 
"North", "South", "South", "South", "South", "South", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "North", "North", "North", "North", "North", "South", 
"South", "South", "South", "South", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West"), value = c("0 (replaced)", "3 (replaced)", "3", "4", "5", 
"0 (replaced)", "0 (replaced)", "1", "28 (replaced)", "2", "0 (replaced)", 
"2 (replaced)", "1", "3", "9", "0 (replaced)", "1 (replaced)", "9 (replaced)", 
"8 (replaced)", "21 (replaced)", "1", "61 (replaced)", "4", "13", "10", 
"2 (replaced)", "12 (replaced)", "48 (replaced)", "32 (replaced)", "3", 
"1", "1", "76 (replaced)", "2", "5", "0 (replaced)", "4 (replaced)", 
"1", "1", "15 (replaced)")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @akrun I think I misunderstood the code. I finally figure out how to get to the solution half an hour ago, I posted the answer so you can see what I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
out <- dat %>% 
  mutate(value_str = replace(value, str_detect(value, "^[0-9]+$"), NA_character_), 
    value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
   group_by(rn, lower, upper) %>% 
   transmute(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), value_str) %>% 
   group_by(rn, lower)  %>%
   group_modify(~add_row(., upper = "Sum", value = sum(.$value))) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(value = coalesce(value_str, as.character(value))) %>% 
  distinct(rn, lower, upper, value) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  summarise(value = list(value))
```

-output

```
> out$value
[[1]]
 [1] "0 (replaced)"  "0"             "5"             "9 (replaced)"  "20"            "16"            "21 (replaced)" "64"            "3 (replaced)" 
[10] "2 (replaced)"  "1 (replaced)"  "7"             "28 (replaced)" "8 (replaced)"  "28"           

[[2]]
 [1] "2"             "2 (replaced)"  "0 (replaced)"  "8"             "5"             "48 (replaced)" "76 (replaced)" "20"            "18"           
[10] "15 (replaced)" "72"            "61 (replaced)" "12 (replaced)" "1"             "4 (replaced)"  "4"             "16"            "32 (replaced)"
[19] "64"
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but maybe you are looking for this:

What we do here is simple paste and collapse all!! the values after unnesting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(rn, upper,direction) %>% 
  summarise(freq = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=TRUE), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
  group_modify(~add_row(.,freq = sum(.$value))) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>%
  summarise(freq = list(freq), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  mutate(freq = paste0(freq, " (replaced)", collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

```
rn    freq                                                          
  <chr> <chr>                                                         
1 A     0 (replaced), 0 (replaced), 0 (replaced), 0 (replaced), 0 (re~
2 B     0 (replaced), 0 (replaced), 1 (replaced), 0 (replaced), 0 (re~
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer TarJae. The thing is that, as shown in the first tibble, not all values are replaced. In addition, the outcome should be a list within the column (altough I guess that is not so hard to fix myself).

Comment: I thought it would maybe be possible to create another value column, force one to numeric and keep one as strings, summarise both of them, get the sum from one and the values from the other. But I can't figure out how to write the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out, although it is far from the cleanest approach:

```
# Only sum values that are not replaced
dat$upper <- as.character(dat$upper)
dat <- dat %>%
    group_by(rn, direction  ) %>% 
    summarise(value = as.character(sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=TRUE)), .groups = 'drop_last', upper="1000001", strata=strata) %>%                  # get sum of sizes
    bind_rows(dat, .)   
# Remove the duplicate rows     
dat <- unique( dat )

# Convert upper back to numeric for sorting                     
dat$upper <- as.numeric(dat$upper)
dat <- dat %>%
    arrange(rn, direction, upper)

# Create list
dat <- dat %>%
    group_by(rn, strata) %>% 
    summarise(freq = list(value), .groups = 'drop')
```